# how to display data from database by checking enums

Tags: php, mysql, enums

so my table is like this....

```
comments   |   status
 asd       |     1
 qwe       |     0
 nmb       |     1
 qwer      |     0
```

so i have here my query update which i use an enum.. if status is 1 the result wont be displayed but if status is 0 it will be displayed..

```
function updatestatuspost($poid,$uid)
{
    $sql = "UPDATE post SET status = '1' WHERE post_id='$poid' AND member_id = '$uid'";
    $query = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $result = ($query->execute() ? true : false);
    return $result;
}
```

this query is for display all the data on my database which limits to 5

```
function getAllPost(){
 $query = "SELECT * FROM post JOIN members ON members.member_id=post.member_id ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 5";
 $result = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
 $result->execute();
 $data = array();
 while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
 $data[] = $row;
}
return $data;
}
```

this query is fine but the problem is the displaying part..

```
<?php
$res=$db->getAllPost();

    foreach ($res as $value)
    {
        if('1' == $value['status'] )
        {
?>
<?php
} else{
?>
   <strong class="font-1-2" style="margin-left:15px;"><?php echo '<a class="text-muted" href="profileview?member_id='.$value['member_id'].'">'.$value['firstname'].' '.$value['lastname'].'</a>';?></strong> 
   }
}
```

what happens is when the if is == 1 all of my data is not being displayed but when if is != 1 all data is being displayed even if other data is = 0.. is there any way to call the value from my db which is 1/0 and compare it using if statement. cause what i wanted to do is when status is if the data has status of 1 it will not be displayed and will be displayed and if is 0..

Comment: I don't understand this bit: `?>
<?php`

Comment: i use that to display my html tags.. without putting it in echo...

Comment: If you want to exclude status == 1 then why retrieve  rows with status = 1 from the database at all? Instead, it seems like your intention is to `SELECT * FROM post JOIN members ON members.member_id=post.member_id /* add this >> */ WHERE status != 1 /* << */ ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 5`.

Comment: i already solve this problem sorry to bother you....  :D